# Error starting executable, no provisioned ios device is connected

Tags: iphone

Why am I seeing this error?  Is it looking for my real iphone device to be connected to install it on their?

I just downloaded the views sample code from: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Fall2010CourseNotes/views%20and%20controllers.html

Comment: completely unrelated to your question, can i get you to email me?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, unless you set it to run in the emulator instead, it'll need to run on an actual device (which requires a provisioning profile). Just select Simulator from the drop down menu in the top left of any window. Note, you'll also have to recompile it, since the simulator runs i386 code, whereas your actual device runs armv6 or armv7.